# Is there any way to get only the last match using logstash grok filter?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Below is partial console output of a Jenkins job. I am trying to capture the Test runs, failures and errors using logstash filter

match => ["message", "(?Tests run: \d+)"]

However this captures all "Tests run" results. I am interested in only the last one.
Is there any way to get only the last match using logstash?

Regards,
Vijay

Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.692 sec
Running com.bmc.hub.ue.PostMergeTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.614 sec
Running com.bmc.hub.ue.MDMOutboundChangeDAOTest
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.665 sec

Results :
Tests run: 85, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Tests run: 23, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.554 sec

Tests run: 85, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 1):

Try the below grok,

```
match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA:Data} (?:Tests run: %{BASE10NUM:TestsRun})\,\s(?:Failures: %{BASE10NUM:Failures})\,\s(?:Errors: %{BASE10NUM:Errors})\,\s(?:Skipped: %{BASE10NUM:Skipped})\,\s(?:Time elapsed: %{BASE10NUM:TimeElapsed})"]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :) !
It worked !!
I just got rid of GREEDYDATA